# Cannot apply image to material

Tags: materials

I am watching a tutorial on how to UV map a model and I have this horse I created.
[image]
There should be a section named 'Surface' beneath the section named 'Preview' which is required to select the image. I have tried restarting blender and it just isn't there. I really hope that I don't have to re install blender.

Comment: Sounds like the tutorial is using *Cycles*, but you are using *Blender Render*.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yea I just remembered seeing a render option at the top and when I switched to cycles render the surface option that was missing appeared so I guess that cleared the mystery thx. If it isn't too much of a bother could you help with my new issue >.< http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35225/blender-wont-allow-me-to-select-a-single-bone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've created a material go to the texture section, and create a new texture ->image. The texture will now be associated with the material.

[image]

Open the image you want to use and then you need to assign some coordinates for the texture mapping and what kind of influence the texture is going to have on the material, the default is Color.

[image]

Comment: But then how does it know that the image is bound to the material?

Comment: Because you add the texture to your material

Comment: in the 1st animation, under the tabs, you can see "Cube > material > texture". This means "Texture" belongs to "Material" belongs to "Cube". In other words Texture is a part of Cube's Material.

Comment: @bithur thanks that helps a lot but am still confused as to why my gui is so different from the one in the tutorial... The video was using version 2.74 and I use 2.73 so there shouldn't be such an extreme difference...

Comment: to keep you sanity try using the version of blender that's used in the tutorial.  you can get all of the versions of blender here: http://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: Are you sure the tutorial is using blender render and not Cycles?

Comment: @cegaton I am not sure nor do I know how to find out...