# Blender won't allow me to select a single bone

Tags: rigging

I am trying to rig this horse model I made (first model I have made as of now) and whenever I try to select a single bone it automatically selects its parents and children bones along with it.[image]
I still have to fix the ears, mouth, and tail but before I do that I would like to rig the legs and neck. Please help.

EDIT: I made sure that all my bones were in pose mode.
EDIT 2: After much tinkering I got it to automatically assign weights that I could then edit but I could not create my own weights.

Comment: Was the armature in pose mode before you switched to weight paint mode?

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, I don't know if this is relevant but I have the legs as 4 separate armatures, as well as the neck, because I don't know how to join them into 1 armature.

Comment: Select them all and press  `Ctrl J` to join them

Comment: @gandalf3 and I put all 5 armatures into pose mode before switching the mesh into weight paint mode

Comment: @gandalf3 I already tried ctrl + J but it apparently only works on meshes

Comment: @gandalf3 when I do ctrl + J it says Active object is not a selected mesh

Comment: Hm.. Works for me..

Comment: @gandalf3 ok I hid the mesh from view and no wi tworked

Comment: @gandalf3 well merging them worked I am about to try the weight paint

Comment: @gandalf3 nope now the bones are all 1 armature but I still cannot select individual bones in weight paint mode

Comment: maybe you should upload your blendfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clicking your armature, change to Pose Mode or Edit Mode to select single bones. On the picture on your post, click that menu that says "Weight Paint" to choose a different mode.

Pose mode is for positioning your bones in a way that will position your mesh (or leg in this case).

Edit mode is for positioning the initial rest position of the armature.

**To weight paint for a specific bone**, (1) change to pose mode, (2) select the bone you want to paint for, (3) select the mesh, (4) change to weight paint mode, (5) start painting. This will only work if the mesh already has a vertex group with the same name as the bone. These groups are automatically generated if you parent the mesh to the armature and choose "With Empty Groups" or "With Automatic Weights" when parenting.

If you need more details on armatures or weight painting, I recommend a tutorial such one of these:

- [Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Your_First_Animation/2.Animation#Skinning) (skip to skinning section)
- [Blender Guru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging/)
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+armature+tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still important, but it can be helpful for others.

Anyways, you have to add armature modifier to your mesh, in order to be able to select single bones in Weight Paint Mode.